How fast does information travel through air molecules?
You're always told that information travels through air (speed of sound) at appx. 767 mph. This doesn't tell you how fast the transfer of momentum happens between the actual molecules of air.
So how fast does information travel through the actual molecules?
My guess is that it depends on each molecule, (not sure about this case with an air molecule). Probably also depends on the elasticity of each molecule, if that makes sense.
(I'm mainly talking about when 2 air molecules collide, how fast they exchange direction and bounce off of each other)

I don't know much about aerodynamics, but nothing, NOTHING happens instantaneous. Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path gives some hint to refine your question.

@GyroGearloose Yeah good point, foolish guess on my part.

Are you interested in how fast pressure waves can transmit information? Because light can carry information through air a lot faster.

@mmesser314 I'm mainly talking about when 2 air molecules collide, how fast do they exchange direction and bounce off of each other, so to speak.

The kinetic theory of gases assumes that the collisions are instantaneous.  The average collision rate is 5 collisions per nanosecond, so the time of a collision is very short compared to 200 picoseconds.  My searching didn't turn up anything.

@RossMillikan ah okay, thanks for the info. I couldn’t find anything on it either; all I found was stuff about the speed of sound in a gas.

I couldn't find anything about the time that a molecular collision takes, but we can get a rough answer.  The mean speed of air molecules is around $500$ m/s [1][1].  The atoms are about $10^{-10}$ meter in size, so it would take about $2 \cdot 10^{-12}$ seconds for one molecule to fly through another.  I would guess they don't penetrate more than $10\%$ of the way, so the collision time would be around $2 \cdot 10^{-13}$ seconds.
1 THE MOLECULAR DYNAMICS of AIR
